# Ffmpeg - Changing frame rate without re-encoding

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to change the framerate of a video so it runs a little longer.  I don't want to re-encode and I want the audio to remain in sync.  I was able to extract the raw video from the video and then remux using...

```
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -c copy -f h264 video.h264
ffmpeg -r 23.976 -i video.h264 -c copy dest.mp4
```

This creates a video that now runs the correct time with no audio.

How can I get a finished .mp4 with the audio?

Comment: How do you want the audio to remain in sync with the video if you have changed its timing?

Comment: The audio will need to be slowed down also to remain in sync.  How do you tell ffmpeg to slow the audio down with the video?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to adjust the audio speed to match the video and re-encode it, but you can do this without re-encoding the video.

First, compute how much you need to adjust the audio. Assuming this was originally a 25fps video you are slowing to 23.976, your speed factor is 23.976/25 = 0.959. We'll plug that into the `atempo` filter to adjust the speed of the audio, pulling it from the original `source.mkv`.

```
ffmpeg -i source.mkv -r 23.976 -i video.h264 -filter_complex "[0:a]atempo=0.959[out]" -map 1:v -map "[out]" -c:a aac -c:v copy out.mp4
```

The `-filter_complex` here is taking the audio stream from the zeroth input file (`source.mkv`) and running it through the `atempo` filter, then naming the output `[out]`. We then use `-map` arguments to say that we want to take that audio stream as well as the video stream from the first input file (starting from zero, so actually the second one, `video.h264`). We have to reencode the audio because we want to change it, but we can just copy the video into the container.

Comment: Thank you tgies. This worked!  The file doesn't always play smoothly.  On some Windows media players I see a slight jitter and on a PS4 it stutters pretty badly.  I thought extracting the video and copying it without re-encoding gave the best results.  Is there anything that can be done to correct this or is this to be expected when copying with a different frame rate?  The video plays about 3 minutes too fast so I just want to slow it down.