# Ffmpeg - Changing frame rate without re-encoding (again)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, framerate

I'm trying to change the frame rate of a MP4 file so it runs at the correct speed.  I asked how to do this with FFmpeg without re-encoding [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1502456/ffmpeg-changing-frame-rate-without-re-encoding) and [the answer tgies gave](https://superuser.com/a/1504299) worked.  This was on a 25fps video.  Now I have a 30fps video and it is not working as I expected.  I changed the `atempo` value by dividing 23.98/30.  The resulting video plays much slower than I want.  Also, the audio is not in sync.  Here's what I did...

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -r 23.98 -i output.h264 -filter_complex "[0:a]atempo=0.7993[out]" -map 1:v -map "[out]" -c:a aac -c:v copy output.mp4
```

Is there something I need to do differently because the source frame rate is now 30?

Comment: "Now I have a 30fps video" -- Are you sure? How do you know?

Comment: Windows and various Media Players show 30fps.  Ffmpeg did also as it was processing it.

Comment: It's challenging to answer without the input files. You may try to use FFprobe with `-show_packets`: `ffprobe -i source.mp4 -show_packets > source.txt` and `ffprobe -i output.h264 -show_packets > output.txt`. Make sure that `duration_time=0.033333` for all packets in `source.txt` and `duration_time=0.041701` for all packets in `output.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.